# Relative abundance of rationals in Cantor's bijection?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can anybody calculate the limit of the relative abundance of rational numbers in the unit intervals (0, 1) and (1000, 1001) appearing in Cantor's famous sequence 1/1, 1/2, 2/1, 1/3, ...?
Can anybody find an interpretation for the fact that it is not 1?

Comment: For this question to make sense, you have to define very carefully what you mean by "relative abundance".

Comment: Calculate the ratio up to every finite index.

Comment: And then what? Take the limit? Have you calculated this limit?

Comment: In a sense (up to any large finite point) about half the terms in the sequence have numerator less than the denominator and so are in $(0,1)$.  A much smaller proportion have the numerator between $1000$ and $1001$ times the denominator and so the ratio between these is not $1:1$

Answer (score 0):

Let $q_1, q_2, ...$ be the enumeration, concerning the Problem:

$$\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\frac{|\{x ∈ \mathbb{R}| n < x \leq n+1\} ∩ \{q_1, q_2, ..., q_k\}|}{|\{x ∈ \mathbb{R} | 0 < x \leq 1\} ∩ \{q_1, q_2, ..., q_k\}|}$$

It has been conjecture that the ratio is:

$$\frac{2}{(+1)(+2)}$$

But proof is still missing.